# Vue.js: PNG image not loading in new tab in production build

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vite

I'm building a Vue.js application using Vite and Vue Router. I have an image WEBP that, when clicked, should open a PNG version of the image in a new tab. This works fine when I'm running the application locally using `npm run dev`, but when I build for production, I get a 404 error when I try to open the image in a new tab.

```html
<div id="art-container">
  <a id="art-link" href="#" target="_blank" title="Loading...">
    <img id="art-image" class="w-auto max-h-96 mb-4 rounded-lg shadow-lg" alt="Artwork" loading="eager" />
  </a>
  <!-- rest of the code -->
</div>
```

artDisplay.js

```js
let artData = [
  {
    image: "/img/art/example.webp",
    fullRes: "/img/art/example.png",
    artist: "Art from <a class='text-lg font-semibold text-blue-500' href='https://example.com' target='_blank'>example</a>",
    description: "Cool description",
    hoverText: "Hover text",
  }
];

let currentArtIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * artData.length);

export function updateArtDisplay() {
  document.getElementById("next-art-button").addEventListener("click", nextArt);
  const art = artData[currentArtIndex];
  document.getElementById("art-image").src = art.image;
  document.getElementById("art-link").href = art.fullRes;
  document.getElementById("artist-name").innerHTML = art.artist;
  document.getElementById("art-description").innerHTML = art.description;
  document.getElementById("art-link").title = art.hoverText;
}

function nextArt() {
  currentArtIndex = (currentArtIndex + 1) % artData.length;
  updateArtDisplay();
}
```

router.js

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';

// Import pages here
import index from './views/index.vue';
import notFound from './views/notFound.vue';

const routes = [
  // system pages
  { path: '/', component: index },
  // catch-all route
  { path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*', component: notFound },
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
})

export default router
```

vite.config.js

```js
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { join, parse, resolve } from "path";

const entryPoints = getEntryPoints("index.html");

// convert to route paths
const dynamicRoutes = Object.keys(entryPoints).map(key => `/${key}`);

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  alias: {
    "~": __dirname,
  },
  build: {
    outDir: 'dist',
    base: '/',
    minify: 'esbuild',
    sourcemap: 'true',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: entryPoints,
    },
  },
})

function getEntryPoints(...paths) {
  const entries = paths.map(parse).map(entry => {
    const { dir, base, name, ext } = entry;
    const key = join(dir, name);
    const path = resolve(__dirname, dir, base);
    return [key, path];
  });
  
  const config = Object.fromEntries(entries);
  return config;
}
```

Full code hosted at [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/3kh0/3kh0-vue-project)

Comment: you haven't shown how `<img id="art-image"` ever gets an image to display

Comment: @JaromandaX I submitted an update to include that code. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: oh ... that's unfortunate that you're using `document.getElementById` etc - by the way, every time you click on `next-art-button` you will add `.addEventListener("click", nextArt)` - that aside, the issue is likely in the http server config, since the server is telling you the resource doesn't exist - I take it the path `/img/art/....` is correct? and that's what you observe the browser attempting to load

Comment: I know it is not the best practice, but it works. I highly doubt it is with the server since it is just hosted on Cloudflare pages. The image does show up on the page, it is just when you try to directly visit it in your browser it breaks down

Comment: and you've confirmed the URL is correct and the image does exist?

Comment: Yes, you can see the images are correct with the [Gitlab repo](https://gitlab.com/3kh0/3kh0-vue-project). It is quite the weird issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256934/discussion-between-echo-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: the gitlab repo is not "cloudflare pages" - so, nothing in the gitlab repo confirms that a) the images have been uploaded to the hosting site, and b) that your browser is trying to open the correct URL, and c) that there isn't some config issue on cloudflarte pages that isn't causing the problem

Comment: The images and everything are in one repo, that repo is deployed to Cloudflare pages. The config for cloudflare page is fine, it works with my other sites (case in point) You can even run it locally with `npm run preview`

Comment: If you open the URL for the png without going through your vue app, does it also give a 404 error? e.g. `https://your.domain/img/art/example.png`

Comment: Yes, it still shows a 404 error.

Comment: does `https://your.domain/img/art/example.webp` work?

Comment: After further investigation, I have found that after I clear all saved site data on the browser, I can navigate directly to the image, and it will show, but if I refresh, it processes HTML and gives me a 404 error. Might be something with a vite service worker, I am going to be looking into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### tl;dr

Do not use subfolders in the `image` folder; all files should be like `/img/example.png` instead of `/img/subfolder/example.png`.

### Explaination

After hours of banging at this problem, I have found a fix.

Changing the file location from `/img/art/example.png` to `/img/example.png` seemed to do the trick. How does this rename fix the image loading issue? No clue. I have checked that this is not an issue with Vue-router and VitePWA. This could be an issue with either my specific configuration or Vue itself.